# Вылетает приложение из-за ошибки с bitmap

Tags: bitmap

Программа, где по нажатию на кнопку выводится изображение. Приложение чудесно работает до тех пор пока я его запускаю на смартфоне с Android Studio по USB, но когда провод отсоединяю, то приложение не запускается выдавая ошибку даже до момента нажатия на кнопку. Причём, вылетает без провода оно не сразу, можно несколько раз закрыть-открыть и только потом, а бывает, что и сразу. Если уже начало срываться, то не перезагрузка телефона ни переустановка приложения не спасают. Изображения выводил не большого формата и разных типов - результат один. Ситуация усугубляется отсутствием логов без которых я становлюсь особо беспомощным. Что за хрюк-хрюк?

```
    public void oCg(View view) {     
    preview1 = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    SurfaceHolder sfhTrackHolder = preview1.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    canvas = sfhTrackHolder.lockCanvas();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 400, 300 + 100, 600, paint);


Вылетает из-за 2-х строк ниже:
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.png2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 100, -200, null);

    sfhTrackHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Comment: А где у вас тут обработка ошибок и исключений? Вы в курсе что lockCanvas может вернуть null?

Comment: эээ ... нет их. Не нашёл как это делается, точнее нашел, но для новичка оказалось тяжело. Лепил я эти исключения, лепил ... не прилепил.